# Custom tabBarItem images not appearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbaritem

I've subclassed `UITabBarController` in order to customize the `tabBarItem` titles and images. With the code below, the titles show up correctly, but `xbutton.png` doesn't appear. How can I correctly customize the images?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBar;
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];

    tabBarItem1.title = @"Buy";
    tabBarItem2.title = @"MatchCenter";

    tabBarItem1.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"xbutton.png"];

    tabBarItem2.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"xbutton.png"];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your images are in greyscale. If they are not, then they will not appear.

Comment: Yeah they're greyscale.

Comment: Also make sure they are pngs, open then in your editor and resave them. What happens when you try tabBarItem1 setImage:[UIImage imageName:@"xbutton.png"] 

Also was your image added to Xcode as a file or is part of images.xcassets?

Does it work if you remove .png?